# How to filter by another flag in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

Here's my data

```
Id   Vehicle          Police Number
1    Car              6734         
2    Car              7834
3    Motorcycle       5428
4    Car              4686
4    Motorcycle       5465
5    Car              3244
5    Motorcycle       4576
6    Car              5458
7    Motorcycle       4562
```

What I need is to get all Police Number for Car for people who has Motorcycle

```
Id   Vehicle          Police Number
4    Car              4686
5    Car              3244
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Vehicle, t1.PoliceNumber
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE t1.Vehicle = 'Car' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                                     WHERE t2.Id = t1.Id AND t2.Vehicle = 'Motorcycle');
```

Comment: Even t1 and t2 is similar?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, which however seems to indicate that you don't fully understand my answer.  All my query is doing is to select all car records for which we can also find another record with the _same_ `Id` which is a motorcycle record.